# how to create a roster sheet in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

This is about training management, when an employee requests for training, it goes to approval workflow and once approved, it is like the employee is enrolled.

Once it is approved I want a roster sheet to be created for that course for all the employees registered and who got approved.

The report I need to generate has to be of the enrolled users of one course and one particular session

If I give copy listitem as approved then different courses would come together in the list

The format for the report
[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about having a separate list for the courses and a look-up relationship between that and the attendees list.  You could then create a view with a related list so when you select a course you only see attendees that relate to the selected course.  It is all done with list view web parts so you could filter the attendees to only show those approved etc as needed.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time out and replying. I have created a visual web part and have decided to work in that way

Comment: No worries - good luck